# Substituting Python built-in function name to the a new function

Tags: python, algorithm, input

I'm leaving my first question on this platform. I got a question while solving algorithm problems with Python, but I don't know how to find related official documents on Google. Can you help me?

This is the code down there.

```
input = stdin.readline

T = int(input())
```

Because of the speed, I'm going to replace the input() function with stdin.readline().
I know it works without any grammatical problems, but I don't know how to find relevant concepts or documents.

Comment: You shouldn't do this replacement. The functions work differently. `input()` allows you to specify a prompt, and it removes the newline from the end of the input.

Comment: And the performance difference should be negligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to take user input in python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929272/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-take-user-input-in-python-list)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html Note that there is a search box at the top. You can type the name of the function or module you need information about.

Comment: @moooeeeep This was not exact ansewr but it helped me. Thank you. I wanted information about whether it is okay to replace the above two functions, but now I knew that they should not be replaced because they work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use the `stdin.read` function similar to this:

```
from sys import stdin
print("\n".join(stdin.read().split()))
```

and the

```
input = stdin.readline
```

have already renamed the input function to be the `stdin.read`

,dough the performance difference should be negligible.

I would suggest you use a different interpreter such as pypy3 or use cpython to speeding your program and 
improve the other parts of your program or if you think your algorithm is in the most optimal state possible then just switch to an other programming language.